# access other values in array in coffee script in a loop (framer.js)

Tags: arrays, coffeescript, conditional-statements, framerjs

Hi I'm fairly new to javascript and CoffeeScript, so I'm currently working on a prototype and learning the language simultaneously.

The following block of code does almost what I want it to do except for one important thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
categories.forEach (cat,i) ->
    mainCat= categ[i] = new Layer
     width:185
     height:77
     parent:catSelect.content
     y:13
     x:205*i+20
     image:categories[i]
   categ[i].states.add
    off:
        image: categories[i]
    on:
        image: altCat[i]
   categ[i].on Events.Click, ->
    categ[i].states.next("on","off")

    if categ[i].states.current is "on"
        print "true"
```

Here I have a loop to create category buttons (mainCat) which have 2 states with separate arrays of images attached (categories[] and altCat[]).

I have put this loop in an array, so that now, when i click a  category, I can check its state using categ[i], but that's pretty much where my limits are.

Right now this basically treats objects in my categ[] array as a multiple choice, whereas I want it to only let one object in the array be in the "on" state at a time and, once it's in the "on" state, it needs to show a specific row of cards while keeping other rows hidden in another array (call it cards[]) located in a separate layer/div.

i.e. something like:

```
  if categ[!=i].states.current is "on"
   categ[!=i].states.switch("off")
   cardsRow[!=i].opacity=0
   cardsRow[i].opacity=1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post more context for the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop over all the objects in `categ` to and then check if they are the same as the layer that has been clicked on, to switch them on or off.

The same holds for setting the opacity for a layer in another array, but then you should use the index of the loop to look the layer up:

```
categ[i].on Events.Click, ->
    for l, index in categ
        if categ[i] == l
            l.states.switch("on")
            cards[index].opacity = 1
        else
            l.states.switch("off")
            cards[index].opacity = 0
```

A full prototype with this at work, can be found here: http://share.framerjs.com/2yg7ix83yv1l/
I've replaced the images by background colors to make the layers visible.

Comment: You Sir are a LEGEND. Works beautifully